Optimizing painting of hundreds of components in a container
My app has a piano-roll music editor which uses a code similar to the one below to change the background color of possibly hundreds of litte rectangle components (notes). It's way too slow, you can clearly see the individual squares switching.
How could it be optimized ?
public class TestManyChildrenRepaint {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        
      // Container with many square panels in a grid
      final int NB_SQUARES = 70;
      JPanel squareContainer = new JPanel(new GridLayout(NB_SQUARES, NB_SQUARES, 1, 1));
      List<Square> squares = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i=0; i < NB_SQUARES * NB_SQUARES; i++) {
        var s = new Square();
        squareContainer.add(s);
        squares.add(s);
      }


      // Toggle selection of all squares
      JButton toggle = new JButton("Toggle");
      toggle.addActionListener(e -> squares.forEach(s -> s.toggleSelection()));


      // Build JFrame
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      frame.add(toggle, BorderLayout.WEST);
      frame.add(squareContainer, BorderLayout.EAST);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    });
  }

  private static class Square extends JPanel {

    private boolean selected;

    public Square() {
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
      setSelected(false);
    }

    public void toggleSelection() {
      setSelected(!selected);
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean b) {
      selected = b;
      setBackground(selected ? Color.BLUE : Color.ORANGE);
    }
  }


Is there a good reason to keep using Swing? Not an answer but JavaFX seems to be the modern alternative to old Swing.

150000 lines of code... ;-)

Got it. It was easier to crack with this minimal example. repaint() is called by setBackground(), this generates too many calls to repaint().
I added a Square.paintComponent() method which paints the background based on the selection status. This way I can change the Square background value without having repaint() called. And I call squareContainer.repaint() only at then end when all individual squares have been updated.

I tried this using your method and it still showed some delay.  Perhaps I did it differently than you.  The problem I encountered is that paintComponent is called for each square which slows the painting process as they are being handled sequentially on the EDT. This method doesn't use GridLayout or extend JPanel for each square.   Square is just a simple class with location, size, and color.  The painting is handled by the JPanel that holds the squares.  And the containing panel's paintComponent is only called once for each button click.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestManyChildrenRepaint2 extends JPanel {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final int NB_SQUARES = 70;
    int squareSize = 10;
    int length = NB_SQUARES * squareSize;
    int width = length;
    int colorIndex = 1;
    List<Color> colors = List.of(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN,
            Color.CYAN);
    List<Square> squares = new ArrayList<>();
    Color currentColor = colors.get(0);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TestManyChildrenRepaint2().start());

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(length, width);
    }

    // setup frame, et al
    public void start() {
        for (int x = 0; x < NB_SQUARES * squareSize; x += squareSize) {
            for (int y = 0; y < NB_SQUARES * squareSize; y += squareSize) {
                squares.add(new Square(x, y, squareSize, currentColor));
            }
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton toggle = new JButton("Toggle");
        toggle.addActionListener((ae) -> {
            if (colorIndex >= colors.size()) {
                colorIndex = 0;
            }
            currentColor = colors.get(colorIndex++);
            for (Square sq : squares) {
                sq.setColor(currentColor);
            }
            
            repaint();
        });

        frame.add(toggle, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
       // draw the squares
       for (Square s : squares) {
            g.setColor(s.getColor());
            g.fillRect(s.getxLoc(), s.getyLoc(), s.getSize(), s.getSize());
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK); // border
            g.drawRect(s.getxLoc(), s.getyLoc(), s.getSize(), s.getSize());
        }
    }

    static class Square {
       private int size;
       private int xLoc;
       private int yLoc;
       private Color color;

        public Square(int xLoc, int yLoc, int size, Color color) {
            this.xLoc = xLoc;
            this.yLoc = yLoc;
            this.size = size;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public int getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public int getxLoc() {
            return xLoc;
        }

        public int getyLoc() {
            return yLoc;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
    }

}

